# C3 charts - contents of tooltip clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, c3

I am making charts using [c3.js](http://c3js.org/). I have to make the contents of the tooltip cilckable. Till now, the tooltip is visible only when i hover over the chart. I have some Information which is to be displayed when i click on a link in the tooltip. I couldn't find any help from [c3 documentation](http://c3js.org/reference.html). Snippet of the code i am working on is shown below.

```
$scope.timelineConfig.tooltip.contents = function (data, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
    var $$ = this, config = $$.config,
    titleFormat = config.tooltip_format_title || defaultTitleFormat,
    nameFormat = config.tooltip_format_name || function (name) { return name; },
    valueFormat = config.tooltip_format_value || defaultValueFormat,
    text, i, title, value;
    text = "<div id='tooltip' class='d3-tip'>"; 
    title = dates[data[0].index];
    text += "<span class='info'><b><u>Date</u></b></span><br>";
    text += "<span class='info'>"+ title +"</span><br>";
    text += "<span class='info'><b><u>Features</u> : </b> " + features[data[0].index] + "</span><br>";
    text += "<span class='info'><b><u>Enhancements</u> : </b> " + defects[data[0].index] + "</span><br>";
    text += "</div>";
    return text;
};
```

I have to make the contents (`<span><b><u>Features...</u></b></span>`) clickable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First (if you haven't already done so) override the tooltip position so that it doesn't keep running away when you try to click it.

```
tooltip: {
    position: function () {
        var position = c3.chart.internal.fn.tooltipPosition.apply(this, arguments);
        position.top = 0;
        return position;
    },
```

---

Then you need to override the hideTooltip function so that it doesn't close before your click event can be detected.

```
var originalHideTooltip = chart.internal.hideTooltip
chart.internal.hideTooltip = function () {
    setTimeout(originalHideTooltip, 100)
};
```

---

Then, you just need to override the `pointer-events` style (so that the mouse events are not ignored) and then attach the handler as you normally would in jQuery

```
$(".c3-tooltip-container")
    .css("pointer-events", "auto")
    .on('click', '.info:eq(2)', function () {
        // add click functionality here. you could pass in additional data using the span attributes
        alert($(this).text())
    })
```

Modify the selector as required (like adding the chart wrapper id...)

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5vbeb4k8/

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm commenting on an old question, but just for reference in case anyone else needs it, I modified the above answer to work for my code.

In my CSS:

```
.c3-tooltip-container {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

In JS:

```
c3.chart.internal.fn.hideTooltip = function () {
  setTimeout(c3.chart.internal.fn.hideTooltip, 100);
};
```

The position code seems to be optional. But the fixed top is probably more user-friendly.

```
tooltip: {
    position: function () {
        var position = c3.chart.internal.fn.tooltipPosition.apply(this, arguments);
        position.top = 0;
        return position;
    },
```

Thanks @potatopeelings for getting me started with this -- it was a huge help.