# Closing C3 tooltip after interacting with it

Tags: javascript, css, charts, tooltip, c3.js

I'm learning to use C3.js for charts, and I'd like to get better at customizing tooltip functionality. Normally C3 tooltips appear as you hover over data. [Example here.](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html) They don't persist, and you can't interact with them.

I found some code here on Stack Overflow [(link here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532349/c3-charts-contents-of-tooltip-clickable/47086004#47086004) to add a timeout and CSS to make the tooltip persist and allow the user to interact with it, but I don't know how to make the tooltip close again afterwards, either by the user clicking somewhere on the chart or the tooltip, or by using a timeout. I think it's annoying to have the tooltip remain on the chart forever after it appears.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbkidd/fh4tn17f/)

There should be a function I can call or override, shouldn't there? I tried adding an onclick functionality so that when I clicked a datapoint, it would do something, but I didn't find a way to make it do what I wanted. I followed [this link](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/364) to figure out how to do the onclick.

```
data: {
  columns: [ ['data1', 40, 50, 60, 70, 80] ],
  types: { data1: 'bar'},
  onclick: function(e) { alert(e.value); }
}
```

I'm not sure I care specifically how closing the tooltip would get triggered. Here's the code from the JSFiddle that demonstrates interacting with the tooltip and how it doesn't close.

CSS:

```
.c3-tooltip-container {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 20px;
    pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

JS:

```
var features = dates = defects = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
];

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30000, 20000, 10000, 40000, 15000, 250000],
            ['data2', 100, 200, 100, 40, 150, 250]
        ],
    },
    tooltip: {
        position: function () {
            var position = c3.chart.internal.fn.tooltipPosition.apply(this, arguments);
            position.top = 0;
            return position;
        },
        contents: function (data, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
            var $$ = this, config = $$.config,
            titleFormat = config.tooltip_format_title || defaultTitleFormat,
            nameFormat = config.tooltip_format_name || function (name) { return name; },
            valueFormat = config.tooltip_format_value || defaultValueFormat,
            text, i, title, value;
            text = "<div id='tooltip' class='d3-tip'>";
            title = dates[data[0].index];
            text += "<span class='info'><b><u>Date</u></b></span><br>";
            text += "<span class='info'>" + title + "</span><br>";
            text += "<span class='info'><b><u>Features</u> : </b> " + features[data[0].index] + "</span><br>";
            text += "<span class='info'><b><u>Enhancements</u> : </b> " + defects[data[0].index] + "</span><br>";
            text += "</div>";
            return text;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide tooltip when
***(1)*** you click on it or
***(2)*** timeout passed
you need

- function for changing tooltip visibility
- function for processing click action
- timer storage for timer stop/restart

Something like this:

```
// 1
window.action = function() {
    // do something
    // ...
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    hideTooltip();
}

// timer storage
var timeout;

var chart = c3.generate({
    ...
    tooltip: {
        position: ...
        contents: function (...) {
            // 2
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(hideTooltip, 5000); // auto-hide after 5 seconds

            ...
            text = "<div id='tooltip' class='d3-tip' onclick='window.action()'>";
            ...
            return text;
        }
    }
});

// disable default
c3.chart.internal.fn.hideTooltip = function (){};

// custom tooltip hiding
var hideTooltip = function() {
    d3.select('.c3-tooltip-container').style('display', 'none');
}
```

Have a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/6tuzsckp/1/).

Comment: Nice! Thanks so much.